# Diagram created with Nativescript shows no values (=empty diagram)

Tags: nativescript

When creating a diagram in Nativescript using the RadCartesianChart framework, an empty diagram is generated only --> the diagram does not contain anything anything representing the input data.

In a Nativescript mobile app I want to display near-real-time data obtained from a wearable. Data acquisition and data handling are working fine.

However, I did not achieve to create a viewgraph representing the input data. I can modify its axes, but the graph always stays empty.

Do you have any ideas?

My data.component.html (relevant parts are extracted):

```
<StackLayout class="page page-content">
  <RadCartesianChart tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
     <LinearAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis></LinearAxis>
     <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis></LinearAxis>
     <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries [items]="collectedData" categoryProperty="time" valueProperty="value">
     </LineSeries>
  </RadCartesianChart>
</StackLayout>
```

My data.component.ts (relevant parts extracted):

```
import { Injectable, Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { PlotDatapoint } from "./PlotDatapoint";

@Component({
    selector: "Data",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./data.component.html"
})

@Injectable()

export class DataComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.collectedData = new ObservableArray<PlotDatapoint (this.dataSource);
    console.log (collectedData);
  }

  get dataSource() {
    return [
        { time: 1, value: 10},
        { time: 2, value: 10},
        { time: 3, value: 1},
        { time: 4, value: 3}

    ];
  }
}
```

Actual result --> I get an empty viewgraph.

Expected result --> 
The viewgraph should contain lines or points representing the input data.

My assumption: The communication between the data.component.ts and the data.component.html is not working.

### UPDATE

I prepared a playgroud link here:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=8zpRGL&v=4

In the meantime, I was quite successful in generating quite meaningful viewgraphs. Main problem was the excellent but quite complex Telerik-framework (especially the question "which axis type goes along with which '...Series'").

However, the goal is to display data received from our wearable according to their timestamps. Dropouts should be recognizable:

-- a "CatigoricalAxis" would not be useful.

Instead, the x-axis should be a "LinearAxis" or better "DateTimeContinuousAxis".

**My current problem**: I did not achieve getting a reasonable x-axis-labelling such as "HH:MM". Instead, the Unix-timestamp ALWAYS persists.

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Thank you! Please find a playground link here:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=8zpRGL&v=4

And please have a look to my update.

Comment: Your playground sample is showing fruits on x-axis and their count on garph